LiteralPath does not work for the new-item function
I have the following problem. I have a PowerShell script which takes a path as parameter and it should create a new folder (named by the current date) in the corresponding path. If the path has no spaces and / or brackets like for example G:\Program Files\Utilities\SendTo2024\testPath1 the code works if I use the -Path parameter.
However, if the code has brackets and / or spaces, such as in G:\Programs\Utilities\SendTo2024\testPath1\test folder\[9]t 0p the path is not recognized and as a result of this the code didn't work.
Now i swapped the -Path parameter for the -LiteralPath parameter. But this doesn't work for the New-Item command:
This is my Powershell script:
# Date in the format YYMMDD (Year, Month, Day)

$date = Get-Date -Format "yyMMdd"

# Checks and creates the path, even if it contains spaces or special characters

$directoryPath = Join-Path -Path (Resolve-Path $args[0]) -ChildPath $date

# Creates the folder with the current date as the name in the specified directory

New-Item -Path $directoryPath -ItemType Directory -Force

Input1:
PS G:\Programme\Hilfsprogramme\SendTo2024\testPath1> .\ErstellenOrdnerTag3.ps1 "G:\Programme\Hilfsprogramme\SendTo2024\testPath1\ordner1"

Output1:
    Verzeichnis: G:\Programme\Hilfsprogramme\SendTo2024\testPath1\ordner1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        03.10.2024     11:15                241003

Input2:
PS G:\Programme\Hilfsprogramme\SendTo2024\testPath1> .\ErstellenOrdnerTag3.ps1 "G:\Programme\Hilfsprogramme\SendTo2024\testPath1\test ordner[9]t 0p"

Output2:
Join-Path : Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "Path" gebunden werden, da es NULL ist.
In G:\Programme\Hilfsprogramme\SendTo2024\testPath1\ErstellenOrdnerTag3.ps1:8 Zeichen:34
+ $directoryPath = Join-Path -Path (Resolve-Path $args[0]) -ChildPath $ ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCom
   mand

New-Item : Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "Path" gebunden werden, da es NULL ist.
In G:\Programme\Hilfsprogramme\SendTo2024\testPath1\ErstellenOrdnerTag3.ps1:9 Zeichen:16
+ New-Item -Path $directoryPath -ItemType Directory -Force
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemComm
   and

Is there a possibility that the path is also recognized if it is empty and contains special characters. it is important that it works dynamically for all cases, because the path as input can change. i have already replaced -Path with -LiteralPath, but this does not work with the New-Item function.

Same answer as yesterday: (Resolve-Path $args[0]) -> (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $args[0])
